# Is there a css or html attribute to center the contents of an input tag?

Tags: html, css, alignment

This is probably best explained with a visual.

As shown below, I have two `<input>` elements for the user to enter dates.

[image]

Is there a CSS or HTML attribute that will allow me to center the contents (in my case, the dates) horizontally in the displayed input areas instead of left-aligning them?

Note: I am not trying to align the controls themselves, just what is inside them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="text" style="text-align:center;" />
```

Comment: +1 - I don't believe the OP said there was anything wrong, he just doesn't know about this rule, so this could be phrased a little better :)

Comment: Bad wording on my part, I assumed something with the calendar was breaking CSS.

Comment: The only thing wrong with it is that it is late in the day, and my brain must have locked up on me. Can't believe I couldn't remember that attribute, I've used it dozens of times! Is this how Alzheimer's starts?

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: center`

**CSS**

```
input.date {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="date" type="text" value="123"  />
```

See in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djqqz/).